# Handling errors for broken URL in imagine php liberary (imagick)

Tags: php, error-handling, imagick

This code works normally with valid image URL

```
$src = url_path_encode($src);
$imagine = new Imagine\Imagick\Imagine();
$watermark = $imagine->open(WATERMARK);
$img=$imagine->open($src);
.
.
.
```

But when the URL is broken I get a Fatal error that stop all scripts!
How can I handling this error? If the URL is broken only skip it?

Comment: check that the url is readable before you open it, or download it separately and then feed the local copy into imagick.

Comment: Seriously, separate the code that downloads files from the Imagick code. Although that functionality was included in ImageMagick there was no need to expose it in PHP, and it's a pretty bad idea to do it like that.

Answer (score -1):

Just use exception handling for this:

```
try {
  $img=$imagine->open($src);
}
catch (RuntimeException $e) {
  //do your exception handling here
}
```

Comment: What makes you think Imagick throws RuntimeExceptions? Or that an error is an exception in PHP?

Comment: I don't know if Imagick throws Exceptions or not, but according to the docs, Imagine (which  @ali uses) does: http://imagine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_static/API/

Comment: @Danack I also don't think errors would be the same as exceptions.